# How do I correct mismatched Timestamps for MySQL and PHP without access to server?

Tags: wordpress, mysql, php, timezone

I'm using civiCRM 4.6.2 under Wordpress.

The PHP and MySQL timezone settings are reported as incompatible, MySQL as 12:38 (which is the current clock time here in Zurich) and PHP as 10:38. However, according to my ISP, PHP is also correctly set to use Zurich time. Is there any way either to suppress the warning (which comes every time I start up civiCRM), or to correct the settings – NB: I do not have any programming access to my ISP.

I haven't noticed any problems cuased by this incompatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With WordPress, 90% of the time it's just the WordPress timezone that needs to be reset.  Make sure that's set right as a first step.

Comment: That seemed to do it, thanks! Perhaps the warning message could be extended?

Comment: There's actually been conversation about whether the warning actually tracks anything that matters.  Once the dust settles, better help text and/or a thorough explanation page on the wiki would be worthwhile.